# connect to APNS server error

Tags: iphone, xcode, notifications, push, apple-push-notifications

A friend and I are working on an iPhone app with push notifications. We have a server wit APNS but when we follow the instructions to connect it, we get an error during the building process. We had to import a .a file (libappconnect.a) and a Class called APPconnect.h which looks like this:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface APPconnect : NSObject {
    NSString *apikey;
    NSString *sharedSecret;
    NSString *apiurlString;
}

- (id)initWithUrl:(NSString *)urlString api:(NSString *)key andSharedsecret:(NSString *)shared;

-(NSDictionary *)registerDevice:(NSString *)deviceToken withCustomInfo:(NSString *)custom error:(NSError **)error;

@end
```

When we run the application we get the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_APPconnect", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't know what's wrong. This is my first time using push notifications.

Comment: seems like you are using simulator... push notifications dont work with simulator.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using APNS first time and want to test is Application receiving notification or not 
then you can use the "PushMeBaby" app

download link :
http://stefan.hafeneger.name/download/PushMeBabySource.zip

and description for using  the push me baby app:
http://ameyashetti.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/apple-push-notification-service-tutorial/

Hope from here you can find answer.